# jQuery reorder table row with undetermined size of rows using regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a table with undetermined size of rows.
And there are UP and DOWN buttons for each row.
I'd like to reorder them when click the UP or DOWN buttons.

The followings is the code from now.

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>Text 1</td>
        <td><button id="buttonUp1">buttonUp1</button></td>
        <td><button id="buttonDown1">buttonDown1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>Text 2</td>
        <td><button id="buttonUp2">buttonUp2</button></td>
        <td><button id="buttonDown2">buttonDown2</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
        <td>Text 3</td>
        <td><button id="buttonUp3">buttonUp3</button></td>
        <td><button id="buttonDown3">buttonDown3</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#buttonUp2').click(function(){
  var current = $('#row2');
  current.prev().before(current);
});
$('#buttonDown2').click(function(){
  var current = $('#row2');
  current.next().after(current);
});
```

Now, I hard-coded '#buttonUp2', '#row2' and '#buttonDown2' in jQuery code.
But it needs to apply to the others like '#buttonUp1', '#buttonUp3', '#buttonDown1'...
And since the size is undetermined, it's unlikely to hard-coded all the cases.

Is there any way to use regular expressions in jQuery?

Thanks.

Eric

Comment: I think what you need is a for loop,not regex.
for loop in table.rows.count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use classes:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row1">
        <td>Text 1</td>
        <td><button class="buttonUp">buttonUp1</button></td>
        <td><button class="buttonDown">buttonDown1</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
        <td>Text 2</td>
        <td><button class="buttonUp">buttonUp2</button></td>
        <td><button class="buttonDown">buttonDown2</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
        <td>Text 3</td>
        <td><button class="buttonUp">buttonUp3</button></td>
        <td><button class="buttonDown">buttonDown3</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.buttonUp').click(function(){
  var current = $(this).parent().parent();
  current.prev().before(current);
});
$('.buttonDown').click(function(){
  var current = $(this).parent().parent();
  current.next().after(current);
});
```